# syscall to print all process info

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, debian

I am trying to write a syscall that can print info about all or an indivicual process. like [this](https://github.com/aydanurakca/Linux-Kernel-System-Call) on linux 5. [This](https://github.com/aydanurakca/Linux-Kernel-System-Call) doesn't work with linux 5 and i have tried to re-write it but i can't get process name to print.

```
void list_all_process(char process_info[])

{

struct task_struct *task;



for_each_process (task) { //processleri listelemek icin struck task ini kullandim

    char process[100];

    char uid_str[10];

    char ppid[10];

    int value_ppid;

    char pid[10];

    int value_pid;

    char state[10];

    int value_state;

    

    uid_t uid = __kuid_val(task_uid(task));

    snprintf(uid_str, 10, "%d", uid);



    strcpy(process, uid_str);

    strcat(process, "\t\t");

    

    value_ppid = task_ppid_nr(task);

    

    snprintf(ppid, 10, "%d", value_ppid);

    

    strcat(process, ppid);

    strcat(process, "\t\t");

    

    value_pid = task->pid;

    snprintf(pid, 10, "%d", value_pid);

    strcat(process, pid);

    strcat(process, "\t\t");

    

    /*

    strcat(process, task->comm); ps komutunda comm name verdiginden comm yazdim ama segmentation fault veriyor 

    */

    strcat(process, "\t\t");

    

    value_state = task->state;

    snprintf(state, 10, "%d", value_state);

    strcat(process, state);

    strcat(process, ",");

    strcat(process_info, process);

}



}
```

my code is like this, i am using debian 11.
I have tried to read `/proc` within c but now am trying to read by looping over each task.

Comment: Please fix your formatting and include all errors and output as text in your question.

Comment: Are you sure your buffer lengths' are not exceeded?